# Installing APKs without sdcard or adb

Tags: installation, android

My phone's sdcard reader and usb port are broken. How can I install apks? (no root) I have tried airdroid, dropbox, webhosting and more, but it does not work. My phone has custom android 2.3.3 and it has no proxy support.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.follow these steps:

1> Go to play store and install "Air Droid" app.

2>Air droid app will guide you through the rest setup.this app is used to tranfer files(music,video,documents,images,apks nd many more ).

Note:MAKE SURE YOUR PC AND PHONE ARE CONNECTED TO SAME WI-FI NETWORK.

3.Locate the apk file stored in pc or laptop and send it through the air droid window opened in your pc or laptop window